# Bootstrap dropdown event not firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events

I'm trying to fire a function when a bootstrap `dropdown-menu` is hidden, here's the code I tried:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown-menu").on("hidden.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropup
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Nothing is being written to console, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: As per the document ..

`All dropdown events are fired at the .dropdown-menu's parent element.`

so the code should be something like this

```$('#myDropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add event listeners on the .dropdown-menu’s parent element. in your case `.dropup`
2. You need to use `hidden.bs.dropdown`. The `.collapse` you have used is for Nav's

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropup").on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropup
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```